# multiplying decimal numbers in java

Tags: java, integer, decimal

I have the following code which works when I am multiplying whole numbers however when I try to multiply decimal numbers and display the answer as a decimal number I am getting an error

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

         int num1=Integer.parseInt(textArea_price.getText()); 
         int num2=Integer.parseInt(textArea_quantity.getText());

          int result = num1*num2;
          textField_Name.setText(Integer.toString(result));
```

Any suggestions on what I can change or add to make this code work with decimal numbers is appreciated.

Comment: Please state what error you're seeing, and on what line.

Comment: (And what do you mean by "whole numbers" vs "decimal numbers"?)

Comment: You are aware, that parseInt() can only parse int's, right?

Comment: The error message I am getting is 14:44.56 78[dbg] CShellExt::CShellException in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "12.34"

Comment: @HotLicks He probably wants to parse floating point numbers..

Comment: @quaylar so you mean it will not accept strings and therefore it doesn't accept any characters other than the numbers?

Comment: @FatmaTurk It does not accept string representation of floating point numbers (those with a decimal point :)), but just int's (what you refer to as "whole numbers")..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BigDecimal could be what you want.

```
 textField_Name.setText(
       new BigDecimal(textArea_price.getText())
       .multiply(new BigDecimal(textArea_quantity.getText())).toString());
```

Comment: I'm trying to use what you have here but it's underlining "valueof" part without any recommended assumption. Do you know why that could be?

Comment: @FatmaTurk: Note the spelling: valueOf()

Comment: @FatmaTurk If you use code completion after `v` it should suggest `valueOf`

Comment: @PeterLawrey yeah it does give me the suggestion but then when I have the rest of the code (when its complete) I get this error message **The method valueOf(long) in the type BigDecimal is not applicable for the arguments (String)**

Comment: Sorry, it has to be `new BigDecimal(string)`

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks for your posts.. Now it does what I want it to do.. I appreciate it...

Answer (score 1):

Change `int/Integer` to `double/Double`.

Note that `double` is imprecise (for example `1.2 * 9` gives `10.799999999` when it should be `10.8`). Consider using [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) if exactness is required.

Comment: My guess is that he would want BigDecimal, since he's dealing with money.

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting real numbers in the text fields then use double rather than int.

```
   double num1 = Double.parseDouble(textArea_price.getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Double.parseDouble()` instead of `Integer.parseInt()`. And use `double` type of variables:

`double num1 = Double.parseDouble(textArea.getText());`

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're using the term "decimal number" to (erroneously) refer to numbers containing a "decimal point".  Such numbers are not integers and cannot be parsed by Integer.toString.  They need to be handled as either floating point (float or double) or as BigDecimal.

Answer (score 0):

```
float a = Float.parseFloat("121.12");
float b = Float.parseFloat("0.9");
float res = a*b;
String str = Float.toString(res);
```